# Dropzone: How to open the document when using double clicks on the thumbnail

Tags: dropzone.js, dropzone

I would like to open the document when the user double clicks on a Dropzone thumbnail but cannot seem to find o how to do this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
  file.previewElement.addEventListener("click", function() {
    ...
  });
});
```